# push Data to stack

Tags: java, stack

```
package michael.week.pkg5;

class Employee {
String Fname ;
        String Lname;
        String PhoneNum;
        String Address;
         void setFirst(String First){
             Fname = First ;
         }
         void setlast(String Last){
             Lname  = Last ;
         }
          void setAddress (String address){
             Address = address ;
         }
         void setPhone (String Phone){
             PhoneNum  = Phone ;
         }          
         void display (){
             System.out.println ("the Fist name is :"+ Fname + "  , the last name is :        " + Lname  + "  ,the address is : "+ Address+ "  ,the phone is : "+ PhoneNum);
         }
         }

    package michael.week.pkg5;

     import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.InputStreamReader;





   public class MichaelWeek5 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    class Stck {
    Employee stck [] = new Employee[10];
    int x ;
     void stck (){
        x= -1 ;
    }
    Employee push (Employee item){
        if (x == 9){
            System.out.println ("Stack is full");
        }else stck[++x] = item ;
        return stck[x];
    }
        Employee pop (){
        if (x <0){
            System.out.println (" Stack underflow");
           return stck [x];
        }else 
            return stck[x++];
    }
    }
    InputStreamReader inp = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inp);
    String info2 = null ;
    Stck obj = new Stck();
    Employee obj2 = new Employee ();
    int w = -1 ;
    for (int r=1 ;r>0; ){
   System.out.println("please enter add  to add new employee");
   System.out.println("please enter pop to pop the last added employee");
   System.out.println("please enter exit to exit");
   String choice = br.readLine();
   if(choice.equals("add")){
       System.out.println(w);
       if (w >= 9){
           System.out.println("you reached the maxmum number !");
           continue  ;
       } 
       else {
           w++;
           obj.stck ();
       String info  ;
       System.out.println ("please enter Employee first name :");
       info = br.readLine();

       System.out.println ("please enter Employee last name name :");
       info = br.readLine();

       System.out.println ("please enter Employee address :");
       info = br.readLine();

       System.out.println ("please enter Employee phone number :");
       info = br.readLine();
       }
   } else if(choice.equals("pop")){
           obj.pop();
           w--;
   }else if(choice.equals("exit"))
           break ;
       else {System.out.println (choice + " is wrong choice !") ;
   }
    }

    } 

   }
```

Greetings, 
i am new to java and i am working on this program....... i need to know how can i push the data to the stck ?
note : the push's parameter is type employee, and Employee contains First , Last, Phone , and address. how i can push each of them ? 
here is what i did , and my instructor refused it

```
package week.pkg5;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Week5 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      class Employee {


     String [] Fname = new String [10];
        String[] Lname= new String [10];
        String[] PhoneNum= new String [10];
        String[] Address = new String [10];
        int x= -1 ;
         void increment(){
           x++;

        }
         void PushFirst(String First){
             Fname[x] = First ;
         }
         void Pushlast(String Last){
             Lname [x] = Last ;
         }
         void PushPhone (String Phone){
             PhoneNum [x] = Phone ;
             System.out.println ("the Fist name is :"+ Fname [x]+ "  , the last name is : " + Lname [x] + "  ,the address is : "+ Address[x] + "  ,the phone is : "+ PhoneNum[x]);
         }
         void PushAddress (String address){
             Address [x] = address ;
         }
         void pop (){
             if (x < 0){
                 System.out.println (" No Empolyee !");
             }
             else {

        System.out.println ("the Fist name is :"+ Fname [x]+ "  , the last name is : " + Lname [x] + "  ,the address is : "+ Address[x] + "  ,the phone is : "+ PhoneNum[x]);
        x--;
        }
}
 void display (){
    if (x < 0){
        System.out.println (" No Empolyee !");
    }
    else {
        for (int q = 0 ; q <=x ; q++){
        System.out.println ((q+1)+"- "+"the First name is :"+ Fname [q]+ "  , the last name is : " + Lname [q] + "  ,the address is : "+ Address[q] + "  ,the phone is : "+ PhoneNum[q]);
        }
    }
}
 }
 InputStreamReader inp = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inp);
    Employee obj = new Employee();
    int w = -1 ;
    for (int r=1 ;r>0; ){
   System.out.println("please enter add  to add new employee");
   System.out.println("please enter display  to display all employees list");
   System.out.println("please enter pop to pop the last added employee");
   System.out.println("please enter exit to exit");
   String choice = br.readLine();

   if(choice.equals("add")){


       System.out.println(w);
       if (w >= 9){
           System.out.println("you reached the maxmum number !");
           continue  ;
       } 
       else {
           w++;
           obj.increment();
       String info  ;
       System.out.println ("please enter Employee first name :");
       info = br.readLine();
       obj.PushFirst(info);
       System.out.println ("please enter Employee last name name :");
       info = br.readLine();
       obj.Pushlast(info);
       System.out.println ("please enter Employee address :");
       info = br.readLine();
       obj.PushAddress(info);
       System.out.println ("please enter Employee phone number :");
       info = br.readLine();
       obj.PushPhone(info);}
   }  else if(choice.equals("display")){
           obj.display();
   } else if(choice.equals("pop")){
           obj.pop();
           w--;
   }else if(choice.equals("exit"))
           break ;
       else {System.out.println (choice + " is wrong choice !") ;
   }
    }

} 
 }
```

Comment: You cannot define a non-anonymous inner class like that inside of a method. I suggest you look into [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), which supports stack functionality and is generic. An example use is: `Employee e = ...; Deque<Employee> stack = new ArrayDeque<Employee>(); stack.push(e); assert e == stack.pop();`

Comment: @MichaelShokery Is this homework?

Comment: yes, i did it in a different way ,and the instructor refused it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create a stack of employees and then you can push the whole employee object on to the stack.

```
import java.util.Stack;
...
Employee emp = new Employee();
Stack<Employee> stack = new Stack<Employee>();
stack.push(emp);
```

Comment: i did :Employee stck [] = new Employee[10];

Comment: Do you want to create an implementation yourself... why? when java already provides you with inbuild `Stack`.

Comment: Then if you use array, you need to create a index variable as `top` which starts at -1. Every push operation increments it and every pop operation decrements it. So for push it becomes... 

Employee stck [] = new Employee[10];
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
int top = -1;

stck[++top] = emp1;

Comment: See the [documentation for Stack](http://goo.gl/bZrWN); note it inherits from [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html). Try to instead use the newer [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface, whose functionality is a superset of that of a stack. To quote the documentation, "a more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the `Deque` interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class. For example: `Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();`"

Comment: Didn't he say; he has to create an implementation and that's a requirement.

Comment: why i cant use this :obj.push(obj2.setFirst(info));

Comment: because.. obj2.setFirst(info) doesn't return anything. It's as good as obj.push(void);

Comment: can i do this :String info ;
           System.out.println ("please enter Employee first name :");
           info = br.readLine();
           emp.setFirst(info);
           System.out.println ("please enter Employee last name name :");
           info = br.readLine();
           emp.setlast(info);
           System.out.println ("please enter Employee address :");
           info = br.readLine();
          emp.setAddress(info);
           System.out.println ("please enter Employee phone number :");
           info = br.readLine();
           emp.setPhone(info);
           obj.push(emp);

Answer (score 0):

after creating an object to the class say (here stck) which will hold the data by calling method ex shown below

```
class std
{

  int id;
  string name;
  public:
  void set_id(int i)
  {
      id=i;
  }
  void set_name(string n)
  {
      name = n;
   }
  void disp()
  {
     system.out.println("name"+name+" and id = "+id);
  }
 };

  main()
  {
      std s = new std();
      s.set_id(1);
      s.set_name("sunmoon");
      s.disp();
 }
```

so here you can observe that s is considered as stack and we pushed one person details as like you can create array of object and push n number of person details.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in how you've *modeled* the data.

**Issue #1 (The biggest issue of all)**:
An Employee should not have any internal representation of the stack.  Think objects in the real world.  In your example, each Employee should have:

- a first name
- last name
- address
- phone number

So the member fields :

```
 String [] Fname = new String [10];
 String[] Lname= new String [10];
 String[] PhoneNum= new String [10];
 String[] Address = new String [10];
 int x= -1 ;
```

do not belong.  This leads us to...

**Issue #2** : The way you've modeled the Stack only allows for a fixed number of entries - 10 in your case).  This is not how a stack should work.  Read up on what a Stack is if you are uncertain.  You can model a Stack in Java using a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) - or use the built in [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) that Java provides.  If you decide to create your own version, the important operations that need to be created are:

- push
- pop
- isEmpty

My advice is to start by modelling the employee and pratice by pushing and popping them off of a built in Stack from the JDK until you really understand the operations before you try to create your own.